# WildCards in SSIS filename

Tags: ssis, wildcard

what pattern/wildcard I can use to get the below two files separately? Currently, I am using this pattern `CRM#ContractsBillingAccount*.csv` but both filenames get qualified for it. how to avoid it?

> CRM#ContractsBillingAccount_v_yyyymmdd-hhmm.csv
>
> CRM#ContractsBillingAccountAddresses_v_yyyymmdd-hhmm.csv

I am using SSIS `foreach loop container` and with `foreach file enumerator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below pattern for both files

```
CRM#ContractsBillingAccount_*.csv
CRM#ContractsBillingAccountAddresses_*.csv
```